# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails": for spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am trying to bundle install for rails 4.0.4 with spree 2.2.2 version and i am facing following issue:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
In Gemfile:
    spree (= 2.2.2) ruby depends on
      spree_core (= 2.2.2) ruby depends on
        rails (~> 4.0.5) ruby

```
rails (4.0.4)
```

In my Gemfile:

gem 'spree', '2.2.2'

gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'

gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-2-stable'

Answer (score 1):

Solution for above error which i fixed :
Add following gem dependencies in following way:

gem 'spree', :git => "https://github.com/spree/spree.git", branch: '2-1-stable'

gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => "https://github.com/radar/spree_auth_devise.git", branch: '2-1-stable'

Which solve my problem ,

Also you need to install nokogiri manually

gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries.